# c# . MySql. "INSERT". error

Tags: c#, mysql

The request isn't executed:

```
            mycmd = new MySqlCommand();
            mycmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTRO 'users' (userid, username, password, ipaddr, port, channel, inbox, inboxadm, access, other) VALUES (NULL, 'username2', 'password2', NULL, NULL, 'channel2', NULL, NULL, 'access2', NULL);";
            mycmd.Connection = mconnection;
            mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username2", message.Login);
            mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password2", message.Password);
            mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("channel2", "channel");
            mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("access2", 0);
            mycmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Help to find and correct an error in request.

Exapmle phpmyadmin SQL-query:

```
INSERT INTO `shachat`.`users` (`userid`, `username`, `password`, `ipaddr`, `port`, `channel`, `inbox`, `inboxadm`, `access`, `other`) VALUES (NULL, 'myacc', 'mypass', NULL, NULL, 'administratorY', NULL, NULL, '9', NULL);
```

Comment: Please specify the error message you are receiving

Comment: Might help to specify your error, define the schema for us, and add any other pertinent details.

Comment: Errors aren't present, after "mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery (); " occurs nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right off the bat, I believe

```
INSERT INTRO 'users'
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO users
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is INSERT 'INTRO' the key word is INSERT INTO

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `INSERT INTRO` problem, you need to prefix your parameters with the "at" sign. Also, there's no need for single quotes around character values; they'll cause an error here.

The single quotes around the table name are also a problem; don't confuse them with the backticks. In a case like this, where the table name isn't a reserved word, I prefer to go without the backticks.

```
mycmd = new MySqlCommand();
mycmd.CommandText =
   "INSERT INTO users (userid, username, password, ipaddr, port, channel, inbox, inboxadm, access, other) " +
   "VALUES (NULL, @username2, @password2, NULL, NULL, @channel2, NULL, NULL, @access2, NULL);";
mycmd.Connection = mconnection;
mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username2", message.Login);
mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password2", message.Password);
mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@channel2", "channel");
mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@access2", 0);
mycmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks @Steve - good catch! I get so used to seeing a vapor trail of unnecessary single quotes and backticks in MySQL queries that I don't even see them any more :) I'll update my answer.